# Возможно ли настроить github, чтоб в комментариях программ не отображались кракозябры?

Tags: кодировка, github

[image: неверная кодировка обведена красными рамками]

Как сделать, чтоб не было в комментариях кракозябр, когда залили программу в удаленный репозиторий github? 
Проблемный участок обведен на изображении красной рамкой.

Comment: Исходники в cp1251, а не utf-8?

Comment: исходники в utf-8

Comment: ссылку можно на файл в репозитории?

Comment: https://github.com/Muriam/cpp/blob/master/math/computational_mathematics/lab1_interpolation.cpp

Comment: Кодировка и правда была не utf-8, посмотрите в пул реквест в вашем репозитории. А так, я открыл ссылку на файл, скачал его, открыл в Notepad++ и поменял кодировку на utf-8, после сохранил файл. Пул реквест: https://github.com/Muriam/cpp/pull/1/commits/2fde4d0b548aa11760e6ed09835aa9204590eddb

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я преобразовала исходник в Notepad++ в кодирокву UTF-8, после этого файл сохранила, и снова залила на github. Проблема с кодировкой решена. Кроме того, файл в таком формате без кракозябр открывается в Sublime text. Раньше я мучилась и никак не могла это исправить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в другой кодировке – нужна была `utf-8`.

И одним из вариантов решения – смена кодировки в продвинутом редакторе, например `Notepad++` или `Sublime Text`.

Советом автору будет настройка IDE, чтобы та автоматически создавала файлы в кодировке utf-8.

Comment: Спасибо, я это учту. Оказывается и в Sublime text можно настраивать кодировку. И не знаю, можно ли настраивать её в DEV-C++.